How to prove $\sum_{i=1}^4 1/(5-x_i) \le 1$ given $\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2 = 4$
Given $\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2 = 4$ where $x_i$ are all positive, how to prove $\sum_{i=1}^4 1/(5-x_i) \le 1$?
Someone tells me it can be proved via Rearrangement inequality, but I don't know how.

This is an application of Cauchy-Schwarz

@CraniumClamp How is Cauchy-Schwarz applied here? What I can get is the sum of $x_i$ is $\le$ 4.

The so called tangent line trick can be useful here. Upon noticing that we have equality for $x_i=1$ and keeping in mind that $|x_i|\le 2$ we can consider a function of the form $f(t)=at^2+b-\frac{1}{5-t}$ on $[-2,2]$ and find $a,b$ such that $f$ thus constructed takes, if possible, its minimum at $1$. From $f(1)=f'(1)=0$ we have $a=\frac{1}{32}$ and $b=\frac{7}{32}$ yielding explicitly $$f(t)=\frac{1}{32}t^2+\frac{7}{32}-\frac{1}{5-t}=\frac{(3-t)(t-1)^2}{32(5-t)}\ge 0.$$ That means that we also have $\sum^{4}_{i=1}f(x_i)\ge 0$, i.e. $$\sum\limits^{4}_{i=1}\frac{1}{5-x_i}\le\frac{1}{32}\sum\limits^{4}_{i=1}\left(x_i^2+7\right)=1,$$ as desired.

Works like a magic, especially the factoring step.

Yes, it is called tangent line trick for a reason... The factoring should not be extremely problematic once one realizes that whatever is obtained in the numerator must be divisible by $(t-1)^2$ as $f$, by design, attains an extremum at $1$.

In case you can use Lagrange multipliers, here's how to do it.
Denoting $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, Lagrange function is
$
\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = f(x) + \lambda g(x) =\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{1}{5 - x_i} + \lambda \left( \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2 - 4 \right).
$
Then compute partial derivatives:
$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{1}{(5 - x_i)^2} + 2\lambda x_i = 0 \quad 
$
and
$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda} = \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i^2 - 4.
$
Then, $\lambda = \frac{1}{2x_i (5 - x_i)^2}$ which holds for all $i$.
Since there is only a single value of $\lambda$ and the term to the right is an injective function of $x_i\in [-2,2]$, it means that all $x_i$ are the same, $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4$.
The constraint then yields $4x_i^2 = 4$, that is $x_i = 1$ or $x_i = -1$. Substituting $x_i=-1$ in $f(x)$ we get $\frac 2 3$, whereas $x_i=1$ yields $1$, which is therefore the maximum.
